# Will .net 4.0 runtime work with SQL Server 2000?

Tags: linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, sql-server-2000, entity-framework-4, asp.net-4.0

According to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100708213949/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/27/visual-studio-2010-support-with-sql-server.aspx), Visual Studio 2010 no longer supports SQL Server 2000.  However, it's a bit less clear on whether the runtime (and things like ASP.net 4.0, Linq2SQL and EF) will work with it.  It seems that only the design-time features require SQL Server 2005 or greater according to that article.

I have a project that requires SQL Server 2000 because it has some legacy SQL Server Extended Procs that don't seem to work in later versions of SQL Server (causes crashes, and I don't have the source to the extended procs).  I can do my design work in SQL Server 2005 or 2008 as I don't need the xp's at design time.  But I need to know if the final compiled app will function on SQL Server 2000 or not if I use ASP.NET 4.0 and Linq2SQL or EF.

Anyone have any experience getting this to work?

Alternatively, if it did not work, could I get around the problem by using a second install of SQL Server that is SQL Server 2008 and uses linked tables to the SQL 2000?

Comment: No direct experience, but I guess it would depend on whether the designer generates any code that's not valid for SQL Server 2000.  I forget if 2005 had any new datatypes added to it.  .NET 4 runtime itself won't care.

Comment: Linq-to-SQL still has SQL 2000 support in .net 4.0. Not sure about EF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

[Even SQL Server 2008 Native Client supports SQL Server 2000](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en)